# Calling function overload for a derived class parameter with a base class parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am not sure my title is verbose enough but I don't know how to better put it in words.
Basically I want to have, for example, these classes:

```
class A {};
class B : public A{};
class C : public A{};
```

these two functions:

```
void cry(B* param){ cout << "Wee"; };
void cry(C* param){ cout << "Woo"; };
```

and this piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    A* weener = new B();
    A* wooner = new C();
    cry(weener);
    cry(wooner);
}
```

and I expect this output:

```
wee
woo
```

But this, in my case, this won't even compile. Is this possible? If yes, what is the correct approach?
PS: The cry function *must* be outside the classes

Comment: You may look at [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: You have stumbled upon *double dispatching*. This is not supported directly in C++, but there are patterns which help. See "visitor". But it does pollute your classes somewhat. Can't you make `cry` a pure virtual function of `A` and implement for `B` and `C`? Then call `weener->cry()` etc.

Comment: No, that's not an option, unfortunately

Comment: I don't know if you can do that, but you could use a vitual function in B and C that delegate to the existing `cry` free function, something like `void B::cry(){ cry(this); }` ? Again, I don't know if your limitation are on the free functions or on B/C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround could be defining a single `cry` function that select its behavior depending on the *dynamic type* of its parameter:

```
void cry(A* param)
{
    if( dynamic_cast<B*>(param) ) //do something
        ;
    else if( dynamic_cast<C*>(param) ) // do something else
        ;
}
```

Obviusly, this is resolved at runtime and comes with a (often negligible) performance cost.

Comment: You probably want to store the resulting pointer so as to not cast twice.

Comment: @Quentin Well, you could. But then you should always search a container for every call of cry. It's an option.

Comment: No, I mean `if(B *ptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(param)) { /* use ptr */ }`.

Comment: @Quentin Oh... I need coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast these objects:

```
cry(static_cast<B*>(weener));
cry(static_cast<C*>(wooner));
```

Otherwise compiler will be looking for `cry` function which takes `A*` as argument (because `weener` and `wooner` were declared as type of `A*` indeed).

Comment: Thing is, he *doesn't necessarily know* what type `weener` and `wooner` originally were (see also: type erasure), especially if there is more code we don't know.

Comment: So Paolo M's answer seem to be more appriopriate - but for me it does not compile... so I think the best will be to mix up our answers: use `if()` statement with `static_cast` ;)

Comment: dynamic_cast should be used in this case, and it should compile

Comment: So why am I getting error: "main.cpp: In function ‘void cry(A*)’:
main.cpp:10: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘param’ (of type ‘class A*’) to type ‘class B*’ (source type is not polymorphic)" (g++)?

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski no no no no no don't ! `static_cast` *always* succeeds at runtime, but if the type is wrong it's a one-way trip to UB land !

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski Because `A` has no virtual member functions. That code was presumably just to show the inheritance. If you add a virtual destructor to `A` it will work.

Comment: @AlexandruKis `A` must be polymorphic, i.e. have at least one virtual method. The usual choice is the destructor (which you need to be virtual anyway since you're going to delete derived objects through a pointer to base).